# Can I validate an XML with the schema loaded from a namespace

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-parsing, xml-validation

I have the below `.xml`  file:

`<witd:WITD application="Work item type editor" version="1.0"      xmlns:witd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/workitemtracking/typedef">

       <WORKITEMTYPE>
       . . .

    </WORKITEMTYPE>
    </witd:WITD>`

One of the senior developers is saying that I  should validate that XML and load the schema from this:

```
xmlns:witd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/workitemtracking/typedef"
```

How can do that in .NET?

Comment: That's a *namespace*, not a schema. You'd need to find the schema in order to validate the XML.

Comment: @CharlesMager My exact same thoughts, my mind really is in the gutter with this. I was thinking I am missing something.

Comment: You can find the source code below.  You can use the xsd.exe utillity to create object.  See : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/remoting/synchronizeddispatch.cs,cff519d89e29f4d1